# Search box not returning data (PHP)

Tags: php, search

I have a simple search box which allows me to search for a "Product ID". it will then read through my txt.file to find it. After reading, it will return the full information of the product based on the Product ID searched. As of right now, I'm having trouble returning the information of the product in the next page. I guess its because I don't really know how to compare the product IDs which are in a combination of strings, int and dashes and that's why it returns an empty result.

P.S: the first line of every element in my txt is the Product ID.

My Search Box

```
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="sn">
                <form method="GET" action="fullInfo.php">
                    <p style="text-align: center;">Search for your musical instrument here!</p><br>
                    <input name ="sn" type="text" placeholder="Enter Product ID"><br>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="submit" >
                </form>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

My Search Result (PHP)

```
<?php
$handle = @fopen('listings.txt', "r");
$row = 0;
$count = 0;
$line0 = [];
$line1 = [];
$line2 = [];
$line3 = [];
$line4 = [];
$line5 = [];
$line6 = [];
$line7 = [];
$line8 = [];

if ($handle) {
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $store = fgets($handle, 4096);
        if ($row == 10){
            $row = 0;
            $count++;
        }
        if ($row == 0)
        {
            $line0[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 1) {
            $line1[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 2) {
            $line2[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 3) {
            $line3[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 4) {
            $line4[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 5) {
            $line5[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 6) {
            $line6[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 7) {
            $line7[] = strval($store);
        }
        else if($row == 8) {
            $line8[] = strval($store);
        }
        $row++;
    }

    $sn = 0;

    if (isset($_GET['sn'])) {
        $sn=$_GET['sn'];
    }
    $item = count($line0);

    for ($c=0; $c<$item; $c++)
    {
        if((intval(strnatcmp ($line0[$c], $sn)) == 0)) {
            echo $line0[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line1[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line2[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line3[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line4[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line5[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line6[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line7[$c],"<br>";
            echo $line8[$c],"<br>";
            break;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <?php
        fclose($handle);
    }
    ?>
```

My listings.txt

```
abc-1234-99
Cedric
93482812
cedric@hotmail.com
Guitar
2000
Yamaha
null
New
---------------------------------------------
def-4332-99
Wendy
98238432
wendy@hotmail.com
Guitar
2010
Yamaha
Scratches on the side
Used
---------------------------------------------
fgh-4567-99
Wendy
98238432
wendy@hotmail.com
Guitar
2010
Yamaha
Scratches on the side
Used
---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Well if `$store = fgets($handle, 4096);` is a self-made buffer, and "listing.txt" is a text file and not some data structure in 4 kb blocks, then you are skipping data to be handled by the rest of your code. .... Also I am not too sure on what you mean to accomplish by this code design.

Comment: But i checked, my datas arent being skipped, its just that the string entered in my Search box is unable to compare with the product ids in my txt file.

Comment: But note https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php .... fgets with that 2nd param will indeed read up to that many bytes ahead or until eof, whichever comes sooner. A text file whereas will likely have "un-fixed" length "records".

Comment: I see, you are storing the file contents to your vars 1st before processing. Disregard my earliers, I will take a look at your second section of code. .... A moment later. Yeah a code re-design would make this better debuggable.

Comment: @GetSet i apologize if my codes are abit messy, i'm still quite new to PHP

Comment: Look into the php `file()` command. You could grab the entire file into an array. Then do some text parsing, If `---------------------------------------------` is a consistent delimiter between "records", you could use that to denote distinct records.

Comment: ok but i jsut wanna solve this issue first regarding "if((intval(strnatcmp ($line0[$c], $sn)) == 0))"  i tried to test it with my product IDs as integer and it worked. just not with alphanumeric strings

Comment: `intval()`ing `strnatcmp()` is pointless since the latter already returns an integer. Something else is going on. You would be doing yourself a favor by cleaning up your code to spot the logical error(s). Hence my suggest on using `file()` to read the text file.